# IdentityServer4 - MVC and webapi in same project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

I am developing an identity server with the following requirements:

- Only contributors can have an account.

This should be done by following the following flow:

- In a webapi controller for integration, a post method receives an object.
- This method creates the user by using an instance of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager.

This works fine, however so far this controller is not protected by [Authorize].

In this case, both MVC, and webapi are in the same project.

How can I protect this integration controller?

Comment: Care to explain why it is not protected by `[Authorize]`? One way I can think of is passing an encrypted key as parameter. Something like the date today in UTC encrypted by MD5 or something similar. This way your web api expects a different key everyday. This is easy to implement.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *specific problem you are having*. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).